# Generate an URL? How to build an URL from vector variables?

Tags: r, rvest, stringr, magrittr

I pull account data from a database which returns a user_ID and a tag_ID.

```
  user_ID
> [1] "userId=111111"
  tag_ID
> [1] "tagId=222222"
```

With these two parameters, it allows me to check how many times the account has been viewed. I get there with a .json link like this:

```
check_url <- ("URL/account_views.json?userID=111111&tag_ID=222222")

 read_html(check_url)
> [1] {"numVisitsStr":"00203"}
```

My problem is that I want to build each link url with the proper User_ID and Tag_ID.
When using:

```
url2 <- paste("URL/account_views.json?", "user_ID", "tag_ID", sep = "")
```

this only provides:

```
> url2
[1] "URL/account_views.json?user_ID&tag_ID"
```

The real values do not get parsed. But I need the numbers; not the vector variables

How can I do this?

Thanks for all input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
user_ID <- "userId=111111"
tag_ID <- "tagId=222222"
paste0("URL/account_views.json?", user_ID, "&", tag_ID)
#[1] "URL/account_views.json?userId=111111tagId=222222"
```

Or you can use also use `glue` which is very convenient for such operations

```
glue::glue("URL/account_views.json?{user_ID}&{tag_ID}")
#URL/account_views.json?userId=111111&tagId=222222
```

where strings inside `{}` are treated as R code.